# Exception in Liquibase update java program

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to update database from liquibase java program . I am getting the following exception:

```
:liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.checkDatabaseChangeLogTable(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:605)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.checkDatabaseChangeLogTable(Liquibase.java:602)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.forceReleaseLocks(Liquibase.java:640)
```

Comment: Show us your code and the changelog you are using. [edit] your question don't post code in comments. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)  please

Comment: This exception comes only if the databasechangelog table already exist.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason is I was using old liquibase jar file : liquibase 3.0.2 when I updated it to liquibase 3.5.3 this issue got resolved .